# Addition of new responsibilities without impacting existing design of a C or C++ application

Tags: c++, c

I have requirement where the component is responsible for receiving a message and 
process the message. There should be a generic message interface such as `uint8` array (it is a binary message) and a generic framework, reads from an external configuration file, a list of handlers. The handlers should implement a generic interface such as :-

```
uint8[] process(uint8[] message);
```

Each handler should process the message and return the processed message to the framework, so that framework can hand the processed message to the next handler and so on.
The beauty of this approach is that it would allow adding new capabilities, hopefully at runtime, by adding a new handler in the configuration file. The generic framework should initialize the new handler, put it in its respective position of handlers and pass the message through all the handlers.

I have implemented this approach many times in Java, but I am struggling to implement it in C and C++. For example in C, I was thinking perhaps register each handler's process function via a function pointer to the framework, so that framework can pass message to each of the handler. But I dont know how to inititialize the handlers based on config file. The config file will contain a "String" name of the handler. How does main method map that string name to the handler file?

Any pointers to code where such a pattern exists would be greatly helpful.

Comment: C or C++? You can't have both.

Comment: Why not add Python to the list of languages?

Comment: You want to process some kind of message with some kind of extensible stack of components, using either C++ or C. That doesn't really tell us much. Not a Real Question.

Comment: I added c or c++, because i  have the freedom to choose between either of the two languages. Additionally it would be nice to see the design approach differences between the two. I understand the two approaches would be very different, but each approach would come with its own pro and cons, like speed vs modularity

Comment: @Jimm: Except that you don't. A good C++ implementation will *not* be a functioning C implementation. And a good C implementation will not be a good C++ implementation. And an implementation that tries to work with *both* will be *terrible* for both.

Comment: Why can't you have both? You can mix the languages with extern 'C'

Comment: Any time you try to do dynamic linking, you're far better off sticking to a C interface. You'll avoid problems with name mangling and different versions of templates and countless other gotchas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if your config file says this:

```
handler1.so
handler2.so
handler3.so
```

and you're on a Linux platform, you can do this:

```
void *lib = dlopen(name, RTLD_NOW);
typedef uint8* (handler_t)(uint8*);
handler_t *func = (handler_t*)dlsym("handler");
```

for each name in the config file. This dynamically loads a shared library each of which contains a handler function (named "handler").

For other OS, similar facilities exist (LoadLibrary on Windows for a *.dll for example).

Answer (score 2):

For C, you have a couple of choices.

One is to use `dlsym()` or its equivalent to find the function pointer corresponding to the name of a function specified as a string.

The other is to use an predetermined array of names and the corresponding function pointers.  This gets messy if the interfaces varies (though `dlsym()` has issues there, too).

```
struct func_name
{
    const char *name;
    uint8   (*function)(void);
};

static const struct func_name func_list[] =
{
    { "function1",       function1       },
    { "anotherfunction", anotherfunction },
};
```

You can then use a search (probably a binary search if you keep the names in order, unlike my example) to find the function pointer corresponding to the name.  One advantage of this technique over lookups with `dlsym()` is that the name in the array need not match the function name, so you can provide aliases if that makes sense.

Comment: Perhaps you had same concerns in mind, but one concern i can see is that if i want to configure ONE instance of the above code with the array with function pointers to functions that implement interface 1 ONLY and other instance of the above code with function pointers to functions that implement interface 2, the only way to do is to create a single or multiple array with function pointers of both interface type and then via configuration choose which pointers to use at runtime as opposed to dlsym where the instance one can be configured just with interface 1 and the rest of code is generic

Comment: can you please point to some issues that you alluded to in your post if interface varies?

Comment: The main issue is: _what is the type of the 'pointer to function' part if you have varying prototypes such as `double function1(const char *);` and `void anotherfunction(int, int, const char *, const char *, ...);`_? You have to use casting, or a union, or ... As long as the pointer is correct when you use it (so the pointed-at function is invoked correctly),  it is possible, but it is hard to get rid of all the compiler warnings cleanly. You often end up using `void (*function)(void);` and casts in the table, but then the point of use also requires casts. Using `dlsym()` has similar issues.